# Where to put relative clause in sentence with a future condition?

Tags: conditional-constructions, relative-clauses

I want to know where to put the relative clause in this sentence:

> Code following must be modified when a routine will be available **that
>   automatically shows installed applications**

or

> Code following must be modified when a routine **that
>   automatically shows installed applications** will be available

Thanks

Comment: Both sentences are confusing. Do you maybe mean "The following code must be modified when... etc"? Is it possible to break it into two sentences to make meaning clear?

Comment: The desided meaning is "when the automatic-show-installed-apps routine will be available" -> "please modify the code below"

Comment: Well, this way it is clear. Why don't say just that?

Comment: Eheh, I could do that! But I'd want to know which one is correct... Why are they confusing?

Comment: Do you want to say "The following code must be modified if a routine is available which automatically shows installed applications"?

Comment: The code below is to be modified when the automatic -show-installed -apps routine is available.

Comment: @TRomano So, could this be ok? "The following code must be modified when a routine is available which automatically shows installed applications"

Comment: @TRomano or "when a routine will be available" ?

Comment: @Teejay: it depends on your meaning.  a) we must modify this program if it will be deployed (in the future) on a computer which already has a show-installed-apps routine on it; or b) if you install this program on a computer which has a show-installed-apps routine on it, then you will need to modify this routine.

Comment: Try restating in the active voice for clarity. We can always recast as passive.

Comment: @TRomano The meaning is that, before or after, someone in our team has to implement that routine. When this is done, the code below is to modify too.

Comment: Ah. It is a to-do list item?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed

Comment: Once the routine that shows all installed apps is available, the following code will have to be modified.

Comment: or...  When the routine that shows all installed apps becomes available, the following code must be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your choice of using "once" or "when" to introduce the future condition. But note the use of "becomes" in the when-version.

*Once* the routine that shows all installed apps *is* available, the following code will have to be modified.

*When* the routine that shows all installed apps *becomes* available, the following code must be modified.